# How to stop Banner Ad loading?

Tags: android, admob, ads

Some user intentionally try to click banner ads many times.Due to this we face problem of account suspension or termination. Does anyone know how to stop the ad being loading if it cross some limit(for example 3).

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    if(currentbannerclick>3)
    {

       // some code to not load the ad.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
private void loadAd() {
    // This is a one element array because it needs to be declared final
    // TODO: you should probably load the default value from somewhere because of activity restarts
    final int[] currentBannerClick = {0};

    final AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
            currentBannerClick[0]++;
            if (currentBannerClick[0] > 3) {
                adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                adView.destroy();
            }

            // TODO: save currentBannerClick[0] somewhere, see previous TODO comment
        }
    });

    if (currentBannerClick[0] <= 3) {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(YOUR_DEVICE_ID).build();
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    } else {
        adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout id=container
AdView       id=adView

```
    if(currentbannerclick>3)
    container.removeView(adView);
```

Thank you everyone for your answer.

Comment: But you still load the ad in the background. Wouldn't that generate fake impressions? If you look at my answer, you can see that it doesn't load the ad if not needed.

Comment: Apart from that, you can better use `adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`. Because now people are going to click the ad to get it gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify if Ad is clicked using Activity life-cycle callbacks. you can then find out how much time user clicked your Ad and call `adView.loadAd(adRequest);` only if the user clicked your Ad less than your threshold.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `AdListener` to your `AdView` and increase your click counter in the `onAdLoaded` or `onAdOpened` methods. More info here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#public-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can also limit number of Ads displayed for user in AdMob System. You can set limit of 3 ads per user per minut, hour or day.